# Passive waiting in c# application

Tags: c#, timer, console-application

I am developing a c# console application (which will be converted to a windows service later).

My application starts a lot of timers that execute some code in intervals (once a day, once an hour, etc).

I dont want my console application to exit after setting all the timers.

Right now I am using a while true sentence but I think that it is not the correct way.

Any help?

Comment: Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close");
Console.ReadKey();

Comment: Can you post some code so that we can see what you are (or not) doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

at the end of the code you can add

```
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close"); 
Console.ReadKey();
```

or

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

either of these will stop the console from closing until you press a key.

Answer (score 3):

When I develop windows services I usually create a module (dll) that contains the code that handles all the logic.  Then I create a windows form that calls Start Service and Stop service for development and a Service project for deployment.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Console.ReadKey() after you have set the times while you are using a console application...

when you will convert it to a service you you won't have to use this line anymore because you will implement the timers initialization on "service start" and it will stay up and running when the code block is over

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about your `while` loop.

If you're converting your application to a windows service later anyway, then I would not bother with this. When using a service, you would set up your timers in the start method of the service, and the serivce runs until you stop it. So there's no need for a custom application loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().WaitForExit()
```

will keep everything running until you exit programatically.